# Proof of Smoothness of Projection Maps & Maps to Cartesian Product

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

Loring Tu's in his *An Introduction to Manifolds* discusses the smoothness of a projection map in Example 6.17, and the smoothness of a map to a Cartesian product in Exercise 6.18 (Second Edition, page no. 65). They are given below.

[image]

Both the proofs are the straightforward application of the definition of a smooth map between smooth manifolds and eventually uses the following facts.

1. The projection map $p_{\mathbb{R}^m}: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ is smooth. And the restriction of $p_{\mathbb{R}^m}$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is also smooth. (cf. the solution of Example 6.17.)
2. The function $h:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m_1 + m_2}$, $h(x) = (h_1(x), h_2(x))$, is smooth iff $h_1:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m_1}$ and $h_2:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m_2}$ are smooth functions. And the restriction of $h$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also smooth. (It is utilized in the proof of the Exercise 6.18.)

**My Questions**

It is not clear to me how we prove the smoothness of the functions $p_{\mathbb{R}^m}$, $h$, and their restrictions to an open subset of their domains. Do we use the definition of smoothness of a function in terms of infinite differentiability in these cases to prove their smoothness as in all cases the domains are Euclidean vector spaces? Any explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The projection map that your question is about, isn't the same as in the proof you linked, as their domains aren't the same. Could clarify what you mean?
For $h$, you can use the product topology.

Comment: Yes, the smoothness of the projection map is used in the proof linked. I am gonna edit the question a little bit.

Comment: Projection in Euclidean space is *linear*, hence smooth. Equivalence of smoothness of a vector-valued function with smoothness of its components is immediately obvious from the definition of the derivative (again, in Euclidean space).

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: I understand the second sentence of your comment. But I am not sure how linearity implies smoothness of a function (cf. the first sentence of your comment). Could please clarify a little bit?

Comment: Any polynomial — in particular, linear polynomial — is smooth. Prove this, if you insist, by induction on degree.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.